# Writing values from dictionary object to text file only writing last key value pair

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, append, console.writeline

I don't know C# or any programming that well at all, but I want to learn.  I've been searching online last couple days to put together what is supposed to read from 2 text files and output a file (formatted for a json file that I'll just copy/paste into that file).  So I can read from two files, create a dictionary object and write to a file but it's only writing the last item. I believe I'm overwriting over and over until the last part.  How do I append to the file rather than overwrite?

My code:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WriteLangFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string path1 = @"C:\temp\langVars.txt";
                string path2 = @"C:\temp\langValues.txt";

                string[] readVars = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
                string[] readVals = File.ReadAllLines(path2);

                Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryVars = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < readVars.Length; i++)
                {
                    dictionaryVars.Add(readVars[i], readVals[i]);
                }

                string outputPath = ("C:\\temp\\");
                string outputFileName = ("lang.txt");
                string constant, value;

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dictionaryVars)
                {
                    constant = (kvp.Key);
                    value = (kvp.Value);
                    string[] lines = { ("\"LANG_\"" + constant + "\"_LANG \"" + " : { "),
                                       ("\"translations\" : {"),
                                       ("\"Lang.asp\" : {"),
                                       ("\"eng\"" + ": \"" + value + "\""),
                                       ("}"),
                                       ("}"),
                                       ("},")
                    };

                    using (StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(outputPath, outputFileName)))
                    {
                        foreach (var item in lines)
                        {
                            outFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're opening/closing the file within the loop, and you're not using the [constructor of `StreamWriter` that takes the `append` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_).

The best solution is probably to move `StreamWriter` creation outside of the loop so that you only open the file once:

```
using (StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(outputPath, outputFileName)))
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dictionaryVars)
    {
        constant = (kvp.Key);
        value = (kvp.Value);
        string[] lines = { ("\"LANG_\"" + constant + "\"_LANG \"" + " : { "),
                           ("\"translations\" : {"),
                           ("\"Lang.asp\" : {"),
                           ("\"eng\"" + ": \"" + value + "\""),
                           ("}"),
                           ("}"),
                           ("},")
        };

        foreach (var item in lines)
        {
            outFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, if you were to keep the `StreamWriter` creation within the loop, you could construct it like this so that it appends rather than overwriting the file:

```
using (StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(outputPath, outputFileName), append: true))
```

P.S. It looks like you *might* be trying to generate a file with JSON inside it. At present your code does not generate valid JSON. If you want to generate JSON, you should use a serializer such as JSON.NET rather than building the JSON manually (i.e. in an error-prone way).

Comment: Thank you, append did the trick.  When I tried taking it out of the loop the foreach didn't know what the lines array was, so to speak.  I don't know C#, I created a vbscript script that built the json but just wanted to try it in c#.  I was given the daunting task of updating a json file manually from a spreadsheet of over 1200 items to add so I tried it in c#, ran out of time and made something in good old vbscript but went back to the c# one because I couldn't not try and finish!  Yes I read around about a serializer but did not have time to teach myself that too.

Comment: Quick question, I'm trying to format the strings in the array by padding them on the left, do you know why this does not work?  

string[] lines = { ("\"LANG_" + constant + "_LANG \"" + " : { ").PadLeft(4),
("\"translations\" : {").PadLeft(6, ' '),
("\"attLang.asp\" : {").PadLeft(8, ' '),
("\"eng\"" + ": \"" + value + "\"").PadLeft(10, ' '),
("}").PadLeft(8, ' '),
("}").PadLeft(6, ' '),
("},").PadLeft(4, ' ')